# How to parse a List of Map in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to retrieve values from a List of Map from a configuration like below.

```
val tabColMapping = List( Map("table" ->"Emp") -> Map("keyCol" -> "EmpId", "orderingCol" -> "dob"),
                          Map("table" -> "Dept") -> Map("keyCol" -> "deptId", "orderingCol" -> "branch"))
```

Trying to get, for each input table name, expecting the the keyCol and orderingCol values in two different variables.
so if i enter "EMP", it will give me

```
val kc = EmpId
val oc = dob
```

Comment: what is the type, a list of tuple of Map?

Comment: @PedroCorreiaLuís, its a tuple of Map.. not sure i understood correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Well those are some messy configs you got there buddy, you should try to output a better type before, nevertheless you could do something like this:

```
def getMessyConfigs(input: String): List[Option[(String, String)]] = tabColMapping.map(
    mapsTuple =>
      if (mapsTuple._1.values.toList.contains(input)) {

        //I guess this config names never change
        val maybeKC: Option[String] = mapsTuple._2.get("keyCol")
        val maybeOC: Option[String] = mapsTuple._2.get("orderingCol")

        // This will retrieve if both exist otherwise will return None
        for {
          kc <- maybeKC
          oc <- maybeOC
        } yield {
          (kc, oc)
        }
      } else None
  )

  println(getMessyConfigs("Emp"))// this will output a List[Option(String, String)]], you can add the .headOption.flatten at the end of the function if you prefer ( and if you only expect one)

  // If you feel brave enough you can do a get, but I don't recommend
  val (kc, oc): (String, String) = getMessyConfigs("Emp").headOption.flatten.get
```

Comment: @Predro Correia Luis This works great.. but if i have the liberty to change the config then how do you suggest the structure the map.

Comment: val tabColMapping = (Map("tableName" ->"Emp" ,"keyCol" -> "EmpId", "orderingCol" -> "dob"),  Map("tableName" ->"Dept","keyCol" -> "deptId", "orderingCol" ->"branch")                  ) if I make the input string like this then will it be helpful

Comment: That is better for sure, but to better structure your configs I would have to know a bit more, for example are these configs static? Can you have more than one config at the same time? Do you have or expect to have more cases in the future? What is the purpose of these configs?

Comment: This is more like static and if any new key added then it will be across all the maps in the list. The purpose of such config is to get the necessary key columns for the downstream. for ex, when i pass emp as table name then I want to collect all the key columns for that table, so that i can use those when needed for the transformation. I hope this helps.

Comment: Well if it is a thing completely static, then you could have a list of configs, and then you would just call config 1-> values, and if you can manipulate the values at ease, I would do it like this:

case class Config( keyCol: String, orderingCol: String)

val configEmp = Config(keyCol = "EmpId", orderingCol = "dob")
val configDept = Config(keyCol = "deptId", orderingCol = "branch")
val configMore = Config(???,???)

val configs = List(configEmp, configDept, configMore)

Comment: Or add a key if you want to control it by a variable:

case class Config(key:String, keyCol: String, orderingCol: String),

val configEmp = Config(key = "Emp", keyCol = "EmpId", orderingCol = "dob")

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it

The keys are parameterized, so you can this method with necessary key,

```
println(getNestedConfig(tabColMapping, "Dept", "keyCol"))

def getNestedConfig(ip: List[(Map[String, String], Map[String, String])], parentKey: String, childKey: String): Option[String] = {
    val pk = ip.filter(i => i._1.toList.filter(i1 => i1._2 == parentKey).size > 0)

    if (pk.isEmpty)
      None
    else
      pk.head._2.get(childKey)
  }
```